# How can i query Memcache data?

Tags: linux, memcached, devops

I'm trying to query and get the data in Memcache from command line.

Port is 11211

I have tried echo "stats cachedump 1 100" but this will not give me data inside it.

Can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 3):

You can query memcached on cli through telnet interface.

First connect to memcached:

`telnet 127.0.0.1 11211`

Then query:

`GET mykey`

`SET mykey myval`

Refer to [memcached cheat sheet](https://lzone.de/cheat-sheet/memcached) for more info.